# Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in ---- on line 18

I keep getting this error. What I want to happen is for when you click the delete button on a post it will delete it.
This is line 18

```
$result->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['delpost']));
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_GET['delpost'])) { 

    $result = mysqli_query( $connection,'DELETE FROM blog WHERE id = :id') ;
    $result->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['delpost']));

    header('Location: blog.php?action=deleted');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_array()/mysqli\_fetch\_assoc()/mysqli\_fetch\_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli\_result, boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysqli-fetch-array-mysqli-fetch-assoc-mysqli-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1)  The error message is slightly different, but for the same reason and the same underlying cause.  `mysqli_query()` is failing and returning a value of `false`.  Check `mysql_error()`.

Comment: Are you using `mysqli` or `PDO`? Placeholders beginning with `:` are only for PDO.

Comment: @David The problem is that he's calling `mysqi_query` when he should be calling `mysqli_prepare`.

Comment: @Barmar: I'm seeing that now too, ya.  Of course, `mysql_error()` would also reveal the fact that the query is being executed without using the parameter, so still useful for his own debugging :)

Comment: @David It would probably say that there's a syntax error near `:id`, but I doubt that would be very helpful to him in figuring out what's wrong.

Comment: If you don't already have good understanding of how MySQL works, its error messages can be very inscrutable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `prepare()` to create a prepared statement, not `query`. You're also mixing PDO and mysqli, that won't work.

If you're using PDO, it should be:

```
$result = $connection->prepare('DELETE FROM blog WHERE id = :id');
$result->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['delpost']));
```

If you're using mysqli, it should be:

```
$result = $connection->prepare('DELETE FROM blog WHERE id = ?');
$result->bind_param('i', $_GET['delpost']);
$result->execute();
```

Comment: must pin this answer

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works check how you provided your values for table.. write is like this:

```
insert into `table_name`(`column_name`) values('values')
```

Use single quote for values

Hope it helps.