# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I used this code for another table it works fine and then when I used it for another table of the same database it shows me this error

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in

I found some solution I tried but that solution cannot help me

```
$heroes = array(); 

$sql = "SELECT id,class_name,image,url FROM time_table;";
mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8');

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($id,$class_name,$image,$url);

while($stmt->fetch()){

    $temp = [
        'id'=>$id,
        'class_name'=>$class_name,
        'image'=>$image,
        'url'=>$url 
    ];
    array_push($heroes, $temp);
}

echo json_encode($heroes);
```

Comment: What was that solution that "can not help me"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051933/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-execute-on-boolean-in?rq=1      i see this solution , in this they tell about to use prepare() statement but i used this already

Comment: If an error occures, `->prepare()` can return false: `mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred.` - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php Consult http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php to find out how to retrieve the last error so you can fix it